# Error serializing asp.net objects (table)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, serialization

I want to save a whole asp table to SQL as an object, instead of saving each element of the table and then rebuilding the table from that. What I had in mind was serializing the object, saving it to SQL as a string and then retrieving it and deserializing it when needed. What I did was pass the table to the Serialize method:

```
public static string Serialize(Table table)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Table));
        TextWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, table);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
```

But this line

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Table));
```

Gives me the exception:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code There was an
>   error reflecting type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table'.

This only happens with the Table type, of all types I've tried.

Comment: It is clear from the  message that you can not create instace of XmlSerializer of type of webcontrols

Answer (score 0):

The type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table` is not marked [Serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and does not implement [ISerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx). Without either of these, you cannot serialize it. You cannot even serialize the [Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) property. [TableRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow(v=vs.110).aspx) and other classes it uses are not serializable.

The best way is to probably read the values out of the Rows property into something you can serialize (e.g. a `List<List<string>>` or, preferably, something more strongly typed) and serialize that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and populate its properties with values from your table and serialize that object

Like

public class SomeClass{
Properties. ...}

SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass()

Populate it

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(SomeClass).

Something like this